# Expansion of Gaussian wavepacket in terms of sines

Tags: fourier-series, mathematical-physics

From [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.09435) paper, I am trying to compute the coefficients in the expansion of the Gaussian wavepacket

$$\phi(x) = \frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}}\exp \Big(-\frac{(x-x_{0})^{2}}{4\sigma^{2}} + ik_{0}(x-x_{0})\Big) $$ where $\sigma << 1$ and $k_{0} >> \frac{1}{\sigma}$
in terms of the functions $$ \psi_{n}(x) = \sqrt{2}\sin(n\pi x).$$

My attempt is as follows:

$$\phi(x) = \sum_{m}\alpha_{m}\psi_{m}(x) $$

From the orthogonality of sines, we have $$ \int_{0}^{1}\psi_{m}(x) \psi_{n}(x) dx = 2 \delta_{mn}.$$ This gives us
$$ \alpha_{n} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\frac{1}{(2\pi\sigma^2)^{\frac{1}{4}}} \int_{0}^{1} dx \sin(n \pi x) \exp \Big(-\frac{(x-x_{0})^{2}}{4\sigma^{2}} + ik_{0}(x-x_{0})\Big).$$

My next step is to write the sine in terms of exponential functions and to complete the square on both terms to get:

$$ \alpha_{n} = \frac{1}{2i}\frac{1}{(8\pi \sigma^{2})^{\frac{1}{4}}}\int_{0}^{+1}dx\Bigg(\exp\Big[-\frac{1}{4\sigma^{2}}(x-a_{+})^{2} -\sigma^2(k_{0}+\pi n)^2 +2in \pi x_{0}\Big] - \exp\Big[-\frac{1}{4\sigma^{2}}(x-a_{-})^{2} -\sigma^2(k_{0}-\pi n)^2 -2in \pi x_{0}\Big]\Bigg)$$

Here, $$a_{\pm} = 2\sigma^{2}\Big(\pm i n \pi + \frac{x_{0}}{2 \sigma^{2}} +ik_{0}\Big)$$

The next step is to use the fact that $\sigma << 1$ to extend the upper limit to $ \infty$ and treat the integral as approximately Gaussian. I get the following approximate result:

$$\alpha_{n} \approx -i(2 \pi \sigma^{2})^{\frac{1}{4}}\Bigg(\exp\Big[-\sigma^2(k_{0}+\pi n)^2 +2in \pi x_{0}\Big] - \exp\Big[-\sigma^2(k_{0}-\pi n)^2 -2in \pi x_{0}\Big]\Bigg)$$

But the correct answer according to the paper is

$$\alpha_{n} \approx i(2 \pi \sigma^{2})^{\frac{1}{4}} \exp\Big[-(k_{0}-\pi n)^{2} \sigma^{2} + i (k_{0} - \pi n) x_{0}\Big]$$

Would this problem be better solved using the stationary phase method or using the error function? Or do I have the right idea here?

Comment: Why are you integrating over a period of $1$ when $\sin(\pi x)$ has a period of $2$?

Comment: You can get $\ll$ and $\gg$ using `\ll`and `\gg`, respectively.

Comment: Also, I believe a $\sin$ series only accounts for the imaginary component of $\phi(x)$, You need an exponential series (which can be expressed with $\cos$ and $\sin$ terms) to account for both real and imaginary components of $\phi(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function

$$\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt[4]{2 \pi \sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{4 \sigma^2}+i k_0 (x-x_0)\right)\tag{1}$$

can be represented by the 1-periodic Fourier series

$$\phi(x)=\frac{a_1(0)}{2}+\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_1(n) \cos(2 \pi n x)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^N b_1(n) \sin(2 \pi n x)\right)\tag{2}$$

where

$$a_1(n)=2 \int\limits_0^1 \phi(x) \cos(2 \pi n x) \, dx=\\\sqrt[4]{\frac{\pi }{2}} \sqrt{\sigma} \left(e^{-\sigma^2 (k_0+2 \pi n)^2+2 i \pi n x_0} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0+2 \pi n)\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0-1}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0+2 \pi n)\right)\right)+e^{\sigma^2 \left(-(k_0-2 \pi n)^2\right)-2 i \pi n x_0} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0-2 \pi n)\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0-1}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0-2 \pi n)\right)\right)\right)\tag{3}$$

and

$$b_1(n)=2 \int\limits_0^1 \phi(x) \sin(2 \pi n x) \, dx=\\i \sqrt[4]{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\sigma} \left(e^{-\sigma^2 (k_0+2 \pi n)^2+2 i \pi n x_0} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0-1}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0+2 \pi n)\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0+2 \pi n)\right)\right)+e^{\sigma^2 \left(-(k_0-2 \pi n)^2\right)-2 i \pi n x_0} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0-2 \pi n)\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0-1}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0-2 \pi n)\right)\right)\right)\tag{4}$$

or by the 2-periodic Fourier series

$$\phi(x)=\frac{a_2(0)}{2}+\underset{N\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N a_2(n) \cos(\pi n x)+\sum\limits_{n=1}^N b_2(n) \sin(\pi n x)\right)\tag{5}$$

where

$$a_2(n)=\int\limits_0^2 \phi(x) \cos(\pi n x) \, dx=\\\frac{1}{2} \sqrt[4]{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\sigma} \left(e^{-\sigma^2 (k_0+\pi n)^2+i \pi n x_0} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0+\pi n)\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0-2}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0+\pi n)\right)\right)+e^{\sigma^2 \left(-(k_0-\pi n)^2\right)-i \pi n x_0} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0-\pi  n)\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{1-\frac{x_0}{2}}{\sigma}-i \sigma (k_0-\pi n)\right)\right)\right)\tag{6}$$

and

$$b_2(n)=\int\limits_0^2 \phi(x) \sin(\pi n x) \, dx=\\\frac{1}{2} i \sqrt[4]{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sqrt{\sigma} \left(e^{-\sigma^2 (k_0+\pi n)^2+i \pi n x_0} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0-2}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0+\pi n)\right)-\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0+\pi n)\right)\right)+e^{\sigma^2 \left(-(k_0-\pi n)^2\right)-i \pi n x_0} \left(\text{erf}\left(\frac{x_0}{2 \sigma}+i \sigma (k_0-\pi n)\right)+\text{erf}\left(\frac{1-\frac{x_0}{2}}{\sigma}-i \sigma (k_0-\pi n)\right)\right)\right)\tag{7}.$$

---

The function $\phi(x)$ can also be represented by the "nested" exponential Fourier series

$$\phi(x)=\underset{N, f\to\infty}{\text{lim}}\left(\sum\limits_{n=1}^N \frac{\mu(2 n-1) }{2 n-1} \left(\frac{3 F(0)}{8}\\+\frac{1}{2} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{2 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \cos\left(\frac{\pi k}{2 n-1}\right) \left(F\left(\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}+F\left(-\frac{k}{4 n-2}\right) e^{-\frac{i \pi k x}{2 n-1}}\right)\\-\frac{1}{8} \sum\limits_{k=1}^{4 f (2 n-1)} (-1)^k\, \left(F\left(\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}+F\left(-\frac{k}{8 n-4}\right) e^{-\frac{i \pi k x}{4 n-2}}\right)\right)\right)\tag{8}$$

where $\mu(n)$ is the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function), the evaluation frequency $f$ in the two inner sums over $k$ is assumed to be a positive integer, and

$$F(\omega)=\mathcal{F}_x[\phi(x)](\omega)=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \phi(x) e^{-2 \pi i \omega x} \, dx=2^{3/4} \sqrt[4]{\pi} \sqrt{\sigma} e^{-\sigma^2 (k_0-2 \pi \omega)^2-2 i \pi x_0 \omega}\tag{9}$$

is the Fourier transform of $\phi(x)$.

---

[My related MSO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/462653) provides information on the derivation of formula (8) above (which corresponds to formula (5) in my related MSO question). Formula (8) above can also be evaluated using $\cos$ and $\sin$ terms analogous to formulas (2) and (5) above (see formulas (11) and (12) in my linked MSO question). Since $\phi(x)$ is complex analytic I believe formula (8) above is actually globally convergent for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

---

The figures below illustrate formulas (2), (5), and (8) for $\phi(x)$ above in orange overlaid on $\phi(x)$ defined in formula (1) above in blue using the $\phi(x)$ parameters $\sigma=\frac{1}{10}$ and $k_0=\frac{9}{10}$ where formulas (2), (5), and (8) are all evaluated using the upper evaluation limit $N=10$.

---

Figures (1) and (2) below illustrate the real and imaginary parts of the 1-periodic Fourier series defined in formula (2) above in orange overlaid on the corresponding parts of $\phi(x)$ defined in formula (1) above in blue using the $\phi(x)$ parameter $x_0=\frac{1}{2}$.

---

[image: Illustration of the real part of formula (2) in orange overlaid on the blue reference function Re(phi(x))]

**Figure (1)**: Illustration of the real part of formula (2) in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\Re(\phi(x))$

---

[image: Illustration of the imaginary part of formula (2) in orange overlaid on the blue reference function Im(phi(x))]

**Figure (2)**: Illustration of the imaginary part of formula (2) in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\Im(\phi(x))$

---

Figures (3) and (4) below illustrate the real and imaginary parts of the 2-periodic Fourier series defined in formula (5) above in orange overlaid on the corresponding parts of $\phi(x)$ defined in formula (1) above in blue using the $\phi(x)$ parameter $x_0=1$.

---

[[image: Illustration of the real part of formula (5) in orange overlaid on the blue reference function <span class=]$\Re(\phi(x))$" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgAuE.jpg)

**Figure (3)**: Illustration of the real part of formula (5) in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\Re(\phi(x))$

---

[image: Illustration of the imaginary part of formula (5) in orange overlaid on the blue reference function Im(phi(x))]

**Figure (4)**: Illustration of the imaginary part of formula (5) in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\Im(\phi(x))$

---

Figures (5) and (6) below illustrate the real and imaginary parts of formula (8) above for $\phi(x)$ in orange overlaid on the corresponding parts of $\phi(x)$ defined in formula (1) above in blue using the $\phi(x)$ parameter $x_0=1$ where formula (8) is evaluated using the evaluation limits $f=4$ and $N=10$. Since $\phi(x)$ is complex analytic I believe formula (8) actually converges globally for all $x\in\mathbb{C}$.

---

[image: Illustration of real part of formula (8) for phi(x) in orange overlaid on the blue reference function Re(\phi(x))]

**Figure (5)**: Illustration of real part of formula (8) for $\phi(x)$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\Re(\phi(x))$

---

[image: Illustration of imaginary part of formula (8) for phi(x) in orange overlaid on the blue reference function Im(\phi(x))]

**Figure (6)**: Illustration of imaginary part of formula (8) for $\phi(x)$ in orange overlaid on the blue reference function $\Im(\phi(x))$

---

Comment: Thank you for the detailed and exact answer! I have worked out the Fourier coefficients, but I find a relative minus sign between the erf functions in the second term in $a_{2}(n)$ and $b_{2}(n)$.

Comment: The nested Fourier series is an excellent cherry on top.

Comment: @saad Thanks, the nested Fourier series representation does seem to give a new perspective on the Fourier inversion theorem with respect to the ability to recover a function from its Fourier transform. The nested Fourier series itself is more complicated than the standard Fourier series, but in this case the coefficients actually seem to be somewhat simpler.

Comment: @saad  I evaluated the integrals associated with the Fourier coefficients in formulas (3), (4), (6), and (7) above using Mathematica and the results seem to converge using these derived coefficients. The $\text{erf}(x)$ function is an odd function of $x$ where $\text{erf}(-x)=-\text{erf}(x)$, so I'm wondering if there's a sign difference in your argument of the $\text{erf}(x)$ function that accounts for the sign difference preceding the $\text{erf}(x)$ function.

Comment: @saad This [WolframAlpha evaluation](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-%28%28x-y%29%5E2%2F%284+%5C%5BSigma%5D%5E2%29%29%2BI+k+%28x-y%29%5D%2F%282+%5C%5BPi%5D+%5C%5BSigma%5D%5E2%29%5E%281%2F4%29+Cos%5Bn+%5C%5BPi%5D+x%5D++%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+2%7D%5D), where I set $x_0=y$ and $k_0=k$ since WolframAlpha doesn't like variables with more than one letter, seems consistent with formula (6) above when you account for $-\text{erf}\left(\frac{\text{x0}-2}{2 \sigma }+i \sigma  (\text{k0}+\pi  n)\right)=\text{erf}\left(\frac{2-\text{x0}}{2 \sigma }-i \sigma  (\text{k0}+\pi  n)\right)$.

Comment: You're ri it ght,was a minus sign in the erf.